# What causes horizontal lines on an excitation-emission matrix in fluorometry?

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy, fluorescence, raman

I am doing excitation-emission matrices to test for CDOM, and we just got some brand new quarts cuvettes. When I hold them in front of a light, they're totally clear and clean.

I ran a sample, and in addition to the normal diagonal scattering lines, there are some intense horizontal lines in the lower left of the EEM diagram. We were getting these before with old cuvettes and figured they were just scratched up and that was the cause, but now that they're happening again I'm a little concerned. Is this a normal phenomena or something hardware or sample-specific?

The horizontal lines are part of the excitation signal (y axis) which should be independent of the sample. I was able to run a few samples today before it happened, though.

[image]

Comment: Just some speculation. Are you sure it is not Raman scattering? Those horizontal stripes stop before the Rayleigh line and the gaps get bigger as wavelength increases. Any way to have the software use or plot wavenumbers instead of wavelengths? Also, are the cuvettes Suprasil? The fact that you got several samples run before the problem suggests contamination.

Comment: I am not sure it's not Raman scattering, but since it doesn't always appear I'm inclined to think it's not. The cuvettes are quartz from Hellma; I'm runnign a scan now without the built-in correction factors in case the factory-supplied correction factors are the cause of the problem. Again, since the problem originates in the excitation, I'm assuming it's hardware-related.

Comment: @EdV I reran the same scan but without the "mask scatter" boxes checked. The horizontal lines had disappeared, but so had my data (the big white blob). Looking at this link here, there's no kind of scattering I should get that looks like what's occurring in my data. http://dreem.openfluor.org/tutorials/smoothing/.

Comment: Yeah, this does not make sense to me. The tutorial has nothing similar. The uniform intensities of those artifact bands makes me think the problem is in the software or hardware, but I have no clue how. Do you have a known standard that has worked well in the past?

Comment: @Edv I just started using this machine a couple of months ago, and so far there's no pattern to what gives this signature and what doesn't. The lamp in the machine is brand new as well. Running the same scan and sample without the corrected signals produces a profile that is simply a white to black vertical gradient, but not in the same way those stripes exist in the OP.

Comment: The fact that they’re perfectly flat suggests it’s a baseline correction issue or something like that in the software. Does it even collect emission data at wavelengths well below excitation? Looks like it might be just filling that part of the spectrum in with a flat line

Comment: It does look like a fault to me, in the spectrum you show, the signal is absolutely constant up to 350nm then goes down then rises with scattered or Raman light. It is just non-physical. Whether the fault is in software of mechanical only you can determine. Have you asked the manufacturer about this?

Comment: Not yet porphyrin, I'll ask my PI about it - last time we went to Horiba with a problem, they broke our machine even further.